# Postion of 2d cell using x and y co-ordinates

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to create a class called point which can calculate the position given the co-ordinates and the size of the spread sheet. The following are the results expected from GetPosition method if the size of the spread sheet is 3X3:

[image]

> co-ordinates (0,0) means 0 position
>
> co-ordinates (0,1) means 1 position
>
> co-ordinates (0,2) means 2 position
>
> co-ordinates (1,0) means 3 position
>
> co-ordinates (1,1) means 4 position
>
> co-ordinates (1,2) means 5 position
>
> co-ordinates (2,0) means 6 position
>
> co-ordinates (2,1) means 7 position
>
> co-ordinates (2,2) means 8 position

```
 public struct MyPoint 
    {
        /* eg a in spread sheet of 3X3
         co-ordinates (0,0) means 0 position
         co-ordinates (0,1) means 1 position
         co-ordinates (0,2) means 2 position
         co-ordinates (1,0) means 3 position
         co-ordinates (1,1) means 4 position
         co-ordinates (1,2) means 5 position
         co-ordinates (2,0) means 6 position
         co-ordinates (2,1) means 7 position
         co-ordinates (2,2) means 8 position

         */
        public int Size_X { get; }
        public int Size_Y { get;; }
        public int X { get; }
        public int Y { get; }
        public MyPoint(int x, int y, int size_x,int size_y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.Size_X = size_x;
            this.Size_Y = size_y;
        }
        // algorithm to get position 
       public int GetPosition ()
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: So? `X*Size_Y+Y`?

Comment: @tkausl  thanks let me check!

Comment: @tkausl it work only for square meaning spread sheet which has equal row column right?

Comment: No, @tkausl's forumula works for any aribitrary rectangular region.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula would be `(x * columns) + y`.

```
(0,0) = (0 * 3) + 0 = 0
(0,1) = (0 * 3) + 1 = 1
(0,2) = (0 * 3) + 2 = 2
(1,0) = (1 * 3) + 0 = 3
(1,1) = (1 * 3) + 1 = 4
(1,2) = (1 * 3) + 2 = 5
(2,0) = (2 * 3) + 0 = 6
(2,1) = (2 * 3) + 1 = 7
(2,2) = (2 * 3) + 2 = 8
```

Alternatively, if you observe the pattern, there is a relationship between these coordinates and their respective numbers:

**You are effectively converting numbers from Base 3 (amount of columns) to Base 10:**

For example, the coordinate (1,1) can be read as 11 but in **Base 3**. If you convert it to **Base 10**, you get 4. Similarly, when you convert 21 in Base 3 to Base 10 and you get 7... etc.

However converting numbers to different bases is not something that's built in in C#. Therefore you might as well use the above formula unless you want to go through the hassle of converting numbers to different bases.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue that you have is your X co-ordinates in your example screenshot have 4 possible values (0,1,2,3) because there are 4 rows whereas your Y co-ordinates have only three possbile values (0,1,2) because there are only 3 columns, so it should be 4x3, not 3x4. I would suggest using row and column instead of x and y so you don't get confused.
After you fix that, for any cell given as (row, col) you can get the position with the following formula: row*TotalNoOfColumns+col where row and col are zero based indexes.

Answer (score -3):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<Point>> points = new List<List<Point>>() {
                new List<Point>() { new Point(0,0),new Point(0,1),new Point(0,2),},
                new List<Point>() { new Point(1,0),new Point(1,1),new Point(1,2),},
                new List<Point>() { new Point(2,0),new Point(2,1),new Point(2,2),},
                new List<Point>() { new Point(3,0),new Point(3,1),new Point(3,2),}
            };

        }
    }
}
```